# How to populate Salesforce Lookup Fields on a Standard Page Using URL Parameters

Tags: apex, visualforce, case

While navigating to a standard page from custom page - I am passing URL Parameters to fields on the Standard page.

I am using fieldID to achieve this and it works for all fields except for lookup fields.

As mentioned in [this blog](http://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2010/button-override.php), lookup field can be populated based on ID and Value.
I am passing both ID and values.

Below is the snippet of my URL value:

```
/500/e?
00Na000000ArhgS=SampleProd
&CF00Na000000ArhgS_lkid=a7Za0000000PB6eEAG
&nooverride=1
```

For some reason, this does not populate the values in the lookup field. It should populate as "SampleProd"

Comment: Are you on classic or lightning? That trick won't work on lightning.

Comment: I am using Classic

Answer (score 1):

Looking at a similiar url hack in my org, everything checks out, except for one thing, a missing prefix which causes the two ids to be different:

```
00Na000000ArhgS
CF00Na000000ArhgS_lkid
```

Try changing `00Na000000ArhgS` to `CF00Na000000ArhgS`. Should do the trick.